# Pi 3 using windows iot, deployment failed

Tags: windows-iot

I have VS 2015 professional and trying to run the hello world app on pi 3 using windows 10. I followed all steps  from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/python but I am getting errors as shown below.

I referred to one such question https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c08c6a51-e649-47b8-8058-2830b1532681/problem-deploying-python-apps-on-raspberry-pi?forum=WindowsIoT, but mine is little different. I dont know where is the issue.

Below is the ouput

```
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\backgroundTaskHost.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32legacy.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x5a8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\procthreadexthost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MrmCoreR.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\actxprxy.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\biwinrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreUAPCommonProxyStub.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\App2VS.Debug_ARM.jwrabel\pyuwpbackgroundservice.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.24210.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vccorlib140_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.24210.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vcruntime140_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.24210.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\msvcp140_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\App2VS.Debug_ARM.jwrabel\Python35.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\forwarders\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32legacy.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32legacy.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32legacy.dll'
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Sat Jul 16 19:54:30 2016: Starting Py_Initialize
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CryptoWinRT.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MinUser.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32min.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Sat Jul 16 19:54:31 2016: Finished Py_Initialize
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Web.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Python debugger is present
Python arguments: Python.exe visualstudio_py_remote_launcher.py 5678 c4548b12-65d4-48db-ab6b-fbcf6daa4d25 StartupTask.py
Sat Jul 16 19:54:31 2016: Starting Py_Main...
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\App2VS.Debug_ARM.jwrabel\PythonHome\DLLs\_socket.pyd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\App2VS.Debug_ARM.jwrabel\PythonHome\DLLs\select.pyd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\App2VS.Debug_ARM.jwrabel\PythonHome\DLLs\_ssl.pyd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\App2VS.Debug_ARM.jwrabel\PythonHome\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
2016-07-16 19:54:33.617806: Remote launcher starting ptvsd attach wait with File: StartupTask.py, Port: 5678, Id: c4548b12-65d4-48db-ab6b-fbcf6daa4d25

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\App2VS.Debug_ARM.jwrabel\PythonHome\DLLs\_ptvsdhelper.pyd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wshbth.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nlaapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[556] backgroundTaskHost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Hello World from IOT
The program '[556] python @ tcp://192.168.0.9:5678/?sd=C%3a%5cUsers%5cjwrabel%5cDocuments%5cVisual+Studio+2015%5cProjects%5cApp2%5cApp2&td=C%3a%5cData%5cUsers%5cDefaultAccount%5cAppData%5cLocal%5cDevelopmentFiles%5cApp2VS.Debug_ARM.jwrabel&host=uwp' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Some where visual studio tries and look into the U drive and it is not present in my computer. Can you point me where can i change it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `U drive` is the storage on the Raspberry Pi itself, which Visual Studio maps when it deploys to the remote machine.

I'm also not sure what error you mean - the penultimate line in your pasted output says:

`Hello World from IOT`

.. which is the desired output. So it worked ?

The rest of the output just seems to be the usual info when starting a debug build. There are a bunch of warning about not being able to locate `.pdb` files, but I don't believe that will stop the app from running, you just wont be able to inspect code if you set breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a three part series on the Raspberry Pi 3 and Windows 10 IoT core on my tiny little blog. I hope this helps.

**Install:**

http://iilabscloud.com/install-windows-10-iot-core-raspberry-pi-3/

**Deploy:**

http://iilabscloud.com/deploy-uwp-app-onto-raspberry-pi-3/

There is a second article in the series but I don't have enough reputation points on this forum to post more than two article links.

I am working on using the Pi along with Azure for sustainable living and farming projects. Good luck.

Daniel Jerome
Palm Harbor, Florida

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you have written very nice step by step blog to get started with pi3 and windows iot but I have a very specific issue with deployment of python code on pi3.